# Spring how to initialize multiple datasource ( without spring boot )

Tags: spring

I try to create 2 datasource from my application.properties

All the solutions I found use Spring Boot or old XML way and I don't wan to use it.

What's the equivalent of this spring boot code.

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

My application.properties

```
    datasource.primary.url="url"
    datasource.primary.username="user"
    datasource.primary.password="password"
    datasource.primary.driver-class-name=com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver


    datasource.secondary.url="url"
    datasource.secondary.username="user"
    datasource.secondary.password="password"
    datasource.secondary.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Stack : spring-core, spring-web, spring webmvc, spring-tx, spring-orm,

```
<springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
```

I want to use @Annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did it, i don't know if it s the proper way ...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.yourootpackage")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" }) 
public Class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${datasource.primary.url}")
private String urlDbPrimary;

@Value("${datasource.primary.username}")
private String userDbPrimary;

@Value("${datasource.primary.password}")
private String pwdDbPrimary;

@Value("${datasource.primary.driver-class-name}")
private String driverDbPrimary;

@Value("${datasource.secondary.url}")
private String urlDbSecondary;

@Value("${datasource.secondary.username}")
private String userDbSecondary;

@Value("${datasource.secondary.password}")
private String pwdDbSecondary;

@Value("${datasource.secondary.driver-class-name}")
private String driverDbSecondary;

 // same for secondary

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSourcePrimary() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverDbPrimary);
    dataSource.setUrl(urlDbPrimary);
    dataSource.setUsername(userDbPrimary);
    dataSource.setPassword(pwdDbPrimary);

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceSecondary() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverDbSecondary);
    dataSource.setUrl(urlDbSecondary);
    dataSource.setUsername(userDbSecondary);
    dataSource.setPassword(pwdDbSecondary);

    return dataSource;
}
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `@Primary` annotation.

Comment: And add a name to your secondary bean so you van wire it elsewhere with `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Actually, I have changed the name of the datasource for the answer. I don't have really a primary and secondary db. I have an oracle db and a DB2 db, both are usefull. I just use them with @ Autowired DataSource dataSourceDB2; and @ Autowired DataSource dataSourceOracle; and it works. That gave me no error such as NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.

Comment: I add the @Primary anyway, because if you call your bean with "applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class);" or something i guess it will fail, but no problem with autowired as I do above.